# Stuck on simple partial integration

Tags: integration

$$\int_0^3\frac{|x-y|}9dy=\frac19\left(x-\frac32\right)^2+\frac14$$
Could someone enlighten me regarding this partial integration?

I feel like i'm missing something but I dont know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you show us how you got that answer?

Comment: What "partial" integration are we talking about here? And what is $\;x\;$ ?

Comment: @Dafty: you forgot to specify that $0 \leq x \leq 3$.  Please add this to your question for the sake of future readers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**

$$\int_0^3\frac{|x-y|}{9}dy=\int_0^x\frac{x-y}{9}dy+\int_x^3\frac{y-x}{9}dy$$

Comment: Oh................ wow. Thank you Sami

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Wait Sami, I'm not getting + 1/4 part. Where is 1/4 coming from?

Comment: The result is correct I verified it certainly you have a mistake in your calculus.

Comment: okay let me try again! thanks! really appreciate it